# Android SQLDelight - "NOT NULL constraint failed" on a field that is not nullable

Tags: android, sqlite, sqldelight

Basically as the title says.

I have a UUID field which is declared NOT NULL:

```
sheet_id TEXT AS UUID NOT NULL,
```

The field is mapped from a non-nullable field in our model class:

```
val sheetId: UUID,
```

But there has been a non-trivial number of `Non-fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException` non-fatals logged for that field in Crashlytics.
How is this possible?

The model/table in question has other NOT NULL UUID fields that don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @mtrewartha in the `.sq` file for my insert statements, instead of using `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES ?;`, do it field by field `INSERT INTO <table> (field1, field2, field3 ...) VALUES (?, ?, ? ...);` We stopped seeing that non-fatal after we started doing this.

Comment: Interesting. The issue actually disappeared randomly for me, so it seems to be something transient, but I'll keep that in mind if I see it again. Thanks!